# Unable to click a button using selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, cookies

I am unable to click on the button using selenium and python. I am able to find the class but not the button.

`<button class="optanon-allow-all accept-cookies-button" title="Accept Cookies" aria-label="Accept Cookies" onclick="Optanon.TriggerGoogleAnalyticsEvent('OneTrust Cookie Consent', 'Banner Accept Cookies');" tabindex="3">Accept Cookies</button>`

I tried following but no luck:
1) b.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='accept-cookies-button']//*[text()='Accept Cookies']").click()

Comment: Can you give the rest of the html or a link to it please?  What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below xpath, because your class def is not correct in your xapth:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Accept Cookies')]")).click()
```

**Note** : Please add below imports to your solution :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```